# Does the example for decaying the learning rate in TensorFlow website actually decay the learning rate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was reading the decaying learning rate and thought there might be a mistake in the docs and wanted to confirm. It says that the decay equation is:

> decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
>                           decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)

however, if `global_step  = 0` I'd guess there is never a decay, right? However, look at the example:

```
...
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.1
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                           100000, 0.96, staircase=True)
# Passing global_step to minimize() will increment it at each step.
learning_step = (
    tf.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    .minimize(...my loss..., global_step=global_step)
)
```

It has a `global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)` that is set equal to zero. Thus, no decay. Is this correct deduction?

I thought there might be a caveat due to integer division when staircase function is set to true, but even in integer division that still seems that there is no decay. Or is there a misunderstanding of what staircase does?

Comment: is it just the number of steps that have passed and its just started at zero? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `global_step` is passed to the `minimize` function and will be incremented each time the training operation `learning_step` is run.

It is even written in the commentary of your code:

> `# Passing global_step to minimize() will increment it at each step.`

Comment: I guess it didn't register the first time I went through it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Olivier's answer, the global step is incremented also in [apply_gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#apply_gradients) (which is one of the steps in [minimize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize)).

> If global_step was not None, that operation also increments
>   global_step

So no matter how you do optimization (with just minimize or modifying the gradients), the global step is incremented.